# How do I view the consumed messages of Kafka in Nifi?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-nifi

I have started a Nifi process(Consume Kafka) and connected it to a topic. It is running but I am not able to (don't know) where can I view the messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ConsumeKafka processor runs and generates flowfile for each message. Only when you connect a processor to other components like another processor or an output port, will you be able to visualize the data being moved through.

For starters you can try this:

- Connect `ConsumeKafka` with `LogAttribute` or any other processor for
  that matter.
- Stop or disable the `LogAttribute` processor.
- Now when
  you start `ConsumeKafka`, all the received messages from the
  configured Kafka topic will be queued up in the form of flowfiles.
- Right click that relationship where the flowfiles are queued up and
  click `List Queue` and you can access the queue.
- Click any item on
  the queue, a context menu will come up. Click `View` button and you
  can see the data.

This whole explanation of "viewing" the Kafka message is just to help you in debugging and get started with NiFi. Ideally you would be using other NiFi processors to work out your usecase.

**Example**

You receive messages from Kafka and wants to write it to MongoDB, so you can have the flow as:
[image]
**Note**:
There are record based processors like `ConsumeKafkaRecord` and `PutMongoRecord` but they are basically doing the same thing with more enhancements. Since you're new to this, I have suggested a simple flow. You can find details about the `Record` based processors [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/102183/record-based-processors-in-apache-nifi-12.html) and try that.

Comment: Can you help me with this:
Say, I want to "process" record. By process, I mean to say getting a recordId, checking the person's Id and counting all the messages the person has received. This info can be stored in another topic. Now, once this aggregation is done, I want to check the total no of messages in the person's quota(personId being the key and no of records being the value, hence, updating this value once I receive the corresponding record). How would you suggest this trivial work using Nifi?

Comment: I highly suggest you to post this in the user mailing list: users@nifi.apache.org

Answer (score 2):

You might need to consume messages `--from-beginning` if those messages have been consumed before (and therefore offsets have been committed).

On GetKafka processor, there is a property *Auto Offset Reset* which should be set to *smallest* which is the equivalent of `--from-beginning` in Kafka Console Consumer.

Comment: I understand that. However, I am not able to view the messages because I cannot see anything pertaining to this in UI.

Can you tell me where in the software can I see the read messages? And where  are these consumed messages kept?

Comment: This video might be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yBc7hHvaQU

Comment: I still couldn't figure out from where can I get the data. I want to see the data coming in the kafka. For eg, we type a command: `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic collect-response --from-beginning` and we are able to see all the messages in the topic. How can I achieve that in Nifi? Alternatively, is there any way that I can store these messages in a file or something?

Ignore my dumbness, new to development.

Comment: Any luck with this @hasherBaba?