# How to write a customized processor in Nifi using Python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-nifi

I have a kafka queue running and receiving messages.
I have connected Nifi with that topic(of kafka) using *ConsumeKafka* api.
I want to have a processor which would read this messages and apply some operations over them.

Based on these needs, what would be the best way by being within Nifi?

Comment: `ConsumeKafka` processors are there for different versions in NiFi. What sort of operations do you want to do? Ideally you can leverage the processors available in NiFi to solve your needs almost all the time

Comment: These operations might include a Mongo DB access to the most.

Comment: You have MongoDB processors available in NiFi. You can leverage them.

Comment: Sorry, my bad

I need to read the data from _ConsumeKafka_ and check to which user it belongs, update the response of that user(no of messages by that user) and act accordingly.

Comment: User can be stored in another topic of kafka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383997/how-do-i-view-the-consumed-messages-of-kafka-in-nifi/50389252#50389252) gave me a perfect insight.

I will brief over here, what I did:
[image]

I don't think this needs an explanation.

Comment: While `ExecuteScript` is a nice tool, I highly recommend you to take a look at the processors that  Apache NiFi offers. You can find the processors and its complete usage guide at https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html Then you can leverage the available processors to complete your usecase.

Comment: I did but in vain :(

I will again go through the list and will update you. However, selfish of me to ask, if you come across the better way, please let me know. New to Data Engg, new to Nifi :/